# How to use Google API finance and Google chart API?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-finance

How do I use the Google Finance and Chart APIs? I want to embed them in my website.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm going to give you the benefit of the doubt and assume you already tried looking looking, and couldn't find google's own documentation in google's own search engine?

Answer (score 6):

The Google Chart [developers guide](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/) is excellent, very clear and lots of examples. As well as seeing the code executed inline on those pages, you can cut and paste the examples into your own webpages to see them in action on your local web installation.

For Google finance, start [here](http://code.google.com/apis/finance/), and follow Google's advice!

1. Get familiar with the Google Data APIs.
2. Read the Finance Portfolio Data API Developer's Guide.
3. Refer to the Reference Guide as needed.